# How do I use SetHITTypeNotification in Amazon Mechanical Turk using the Perl SDK?

Tags: perl, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

Has anyone used the createHITType function in the Perl Amazon Mechanical Turk SDK to add Notification properties to their HIT?

I've managed to get it all working. I can grab the balance from both my sandbox account and the live system. I've successfully created new hits using the various techniques in the samples dir, but I need to enable SetHITTypeNotification, passing on properties that tell Amazon to notify me by email when someone accepts/submits a hit.

I've checked through the documentation on AWS and the rough schema would be this:

```
 <Notification>  
  <Destination>me@email.com</Destination>
  <Transport>Email</Transport>  
  <Version>2006-10-31</Version>  
  <EventType>AssignmentAccepted</EventType>
  <EventType>AssignmentSubmitted</EventType>
 </Notification>
```

I've done some grep'ing through the various modules looking for notification and came across the BulkSupport.pm module that seems to make reference to notifications contained as a hash within a properties object passed to the createHITType function.

I also think that it is taking these from perhaps a properties file, but I've specifically learnt Perl to use mturk along with another project, so I am now stumped to figure out what to do. I perldoc'ed the crap out of all the modules too, but there is a complete lack of documentation on implementing notifications from what I can find.

Comment: What about another language. I'm using Perl to deal with some automation (LWP & Mechanize) but if I have to switch to something else for the HIT management I am willing.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution in perl without the need of the XML structure:

```
my $mturk2 = Net::Amazon::MechanicalTurk->new(serviceUrl=>"prod");
my $result2 = $mturk2->SetHITTypeNotification(
                     HITTypeId    => 'EXAMPLE00000000000EXAMPLE00000',
                     Notification => {
                         Transport => 'Email',
                         Destination => 'me@email.com',
                         EventType => 'AssignmentSubmitted',
                         Version => '2006-05-05'
                    },
                    Active       => 'true'
);
print $result->toString;
```

using the module: Net::Amazon::MechanicalTurk